# Is it possible to get somebody's UDID using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, web

I would like to know if you can access people's UDIDs when they go to your website?

If it is possible please point me to a good tutorial if you know one.

Comment: And no, you should not

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 5 you can no longer retrieve a users UDID.  So the answer is no, not in javascript, not in native code, not at all.  Unless you wear a turtleneck...

Answer (score 0):

Not since iOS6, which replaced the accessible UDID with a non-permanent, non-personal device identifier - Advertising Identifier